# Remove all subfolders in Node using globs with the help of rimraf package?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following directory structure:

```
dist
├── a/
├── b/
├── a.md
└── b.md
```

I want to remove the `dist/a` folder & `dist/b` folder (basically all subfolders) with the help of [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) package using **globs**.

I have installed `rimraf` globally as so `npm i -g rimraf`.

I tried doing `rimraf dist/**`, `rimraf dist/*`, `rimraf dist/**/`, `rimraf dist/**/*` but it complete wipes out everything inside `dist/` directory.

I know I can do individually like `rimraf dist/a && rimraf dist/b` but I want to use `globs` since there are many directories in my Node project. Also, this is a part of an npm script but just to give an example I made a short usecase :)

Anyway to do it cross-platform? I also found [del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) package which is quite similar to `rimraf` but can't get it to work either :(

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? do want to keep a.md and b.md only? do you want to remove all subfolders? or keep specific ones?

Comment: Maybe try with `rimraf !(dist/*.md)`

Comment: @OronBen-David i want to delete all sub-folders

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal thanks I actually don't know which file extensions will be there so i'll try `rimraf !(dist/*.*)` to see if it works. **edit:** just tried, it doesn't work. gives `number expected` error. also tried with `*.md` but doesn't work either :(

Comment: @deadcoder0904 yeah you can try that and if it works I will post this as an answer for other guys who might face the same problem

Comment: deadcoder0904 check my answer. You need to use quotes to wrap that pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `rimraf dist/*/` to remove all the subfolders within a particular folder.

This will remove subfolders and will preserve all the other extensions file.

Comment: OMG, thanks it worked. I was doing `rimraf  dist/**/*` because that's how globs work but it didn't. Your solution worked 

Comment: That's because glob's `**`  also matches zero directories, but you wanted at least one.