# node js rimraf delete dist folder in any of the subfolders of src

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, rm, node.js-fs

I have many dist folders inside src folder. It can be nested at any depth.

```
src
    - dist
    - main
        - dist
        - com
            - dist
            ....
    - test
        - dist
        - com
            - dist
```

I need a command in rimraf to delete all such dist folders inside src folder.

I tried rimraf `src/**/dist`, `src/*/dist`, `src/**/*/dist`, but none of them are working, in fact I am getting an error saying `Error: Illegal characters in path.`

If its not possible to do this with rimraf, is there any other simpler solution using node js? The tedious solution might be to write my own script to call rimraf recursively after I get directory structure using fs or something.

Comment: Related to? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056804/remove-all-subfolders-in-node-using-globs-with-the-help-of-rimraf-package

Comment: thats the first link I checked as well. and tried that solution as well :P Either way in that question, op wanted to delete all subfolders and keep regular files. But for me I want to "recursively" delete all dist folders inside my src folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `--glob` flag:

```bash
rimraf src/*/dist --glob
```

### Use case

Here is a basic `init.js` file to get the folder structure set up:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';

await fs.mkdir('src/main/dist', { recursive: true });
await fs.mkdir('src/main/com/dist', { recursive: true });
await fs.mkdir('test/dist', { recursive: true });
await fs.mkdir('test/com/dist', { recursive: true });

console.log('Done...'); // Created all directories
```

And here is the `clean.js`:

```js
import { rimraf } from 'rimraf';

// rimraf src/*/dist --glob
await rimraf('src/*/dist', { glob: true });

console.log("Done..."); // Removed all dist/ (sub)directories
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. By the way I had to use double *. Since the dist folder can be nested at any depth(including depth 0), meaning it could be right inside src folder. Updated my example tree in the question.